# Supersized 3.0 view through iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone

Using the supersized script http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ on a new site.  Same thing happens with the demo site.  http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/3/core.html

When I view it through my iPhone / Android, not seeing the bottom of the site, basically unable to scroll down.

Does this have to do with the CSS or that this script does not work with ?

**EDIT:**
Did not know that jQuery not capable of working on mobile devices.  Guess that why they came up with jQuery mobile...

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as far as I can tell, has to do with the inner block having an absolute position and a height:100%. That prevents the page from scrolling.

Change the position to relative and the inner block shows up below the background.
Change the height to auto and the background does not resize.

The best compromise I've come up with is to add the following to my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
.focus_wrapper { poxsition:relative; height:auto;}
}
```

The image is displayed in the background but if the foreground item is longer than the screen, the background image terminates and doesn't repeat. Sorry I don't have a better answer.